# ipcRenderer.on() gets never called

Tags: javascript, macos, electron

**app.js**

```
app.whenReady().then(() => {
     const win = new BrowserWindow({
         width: 800,
         height: 600
     )}
     win.loadFile('index.html')
     
     win.on("resized", () => {
         console.log("Window resized")
         win.webContents.send("resize", "window resized")
     })
}
```

**script.js**

```
require('electron').ipcRenderer.on('resize', (event, message) => {
    alert("Received!")
})
```

of course I have included it in index.html `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`

Everything looks fine to me but when I run the application and resize the window I see in the console "Window resized" but the message is never received by ipcRenderer.on() function, what am I missing?

I'm running on MacBook m1.

Comment: I don't know which version of Electron you are running but I've made a gist and it's ok ( https://gist.github.com/5d6b14239a8e59ae7d93b05075aab419). Only changes are concerning the webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        } without that we got error require is not defined in the renderer

Comment: `contextIsolation: false` did the trick, I had already tried with `nodeIntegration: true` but I was missing the context isolation, thank you. @AlainBUFERNE